# Passing vector by reference to another class/file

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

I have 2 sets of header+source files. One with the Main GUI class and the other with a Derived GUI class (Main window that opens a second window).

In the Main class I have a vector of strings. I can pass that vector by reference by calling a function in the Derived class and pass it by reference. I can use and update that vector in this function and the changes will be available in the Main class/file. So far so good.

The next thing I would like to do is use this passed by reference vector in all functions in the Derived class.
Up to now, I created and 'extern' vector in a "common" set of header+source.
This make it a global vector, and although its working, it is not the most elegant way.

Is there an alternative way to make the vector available to all functions in the Derived GUI class/file (and add/edit elements that are available in the Main GUI class/file later on)?

MainFrame.h

```
class wxMainFrame: public GUIFrame
{
    public:
        wxMainFrame(wxFrame *frame);
        ~wxMainFrame();
        DerivedFrame *m_DerivedFrame;
    private:
        std::vector<wxString> vwsM3;
        ....etc
}
```

DerivedFrame.h

```
class DerivedFrame: public OtherFrane
{
        public:
            DerivedFrame( wxWindow* parent );
            ~DerivedFrame();
        private:
            std::vector<wxString> vwsM4;
            void PassVector(std::vector<wxString> &vwsM);
            void USEvwsM();
            ....etc
}
```

MainFrame.cpp

```
wxMainFrame::wxMainFrame(wxFrame *frame) : GUIFrame(frame)
{
    m_DerivedFrame = new DerivedFrame(this);
    m_DerivedFrame->PassVector(&vwsM3);
}
```

DerivedFrame.cpp

```
DerivedFrame::DerivedFrame ( wxWindow* parent ) : OtherFrame( parent )
{
    //
}

void DerivedFrame::PassVector(std::vector<wxString> &vwsM)
{
    vwsM.push_back("Something");
}

void USEvwsM()
{
    // ??
}
```

OnInit() (The vector vwsM3 is not known here because its in a seperate header+source file)

```
IMPLEMENT_APP(wxMainApp);

bool wxMainApp::OnInit()
{
    wxMainFrame* frame = new wxMainFrame(0L);
    frame->SetIcon(wxICON(aaaa)); // To Set App Icon
    frame->Show();

    return true;
}
```

Comment: In Derived class you can make field `std::vector<std::string> * pstrs_ = nullptr;`, which you initialize from Main class by calling `derived.SetStrings(&main_strs_);`. You call this Set function just once when you need to initialize Derived class, maybe even in constructor.

Comment: Please include some code to support your question.

Comment: 1) Pass a reference to the vector to the class constructor, and the object stores this reference in a variable (initialized with the constructor initializer list); Or 2) Pass (a reference to) the vector as an argument to all functions that needs it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. To derived class add one more pointer field:

```cpp
class DerivedFrame: public OtherFrame {
    .......
    private:
        std::vector<wxString> * pvwsM3 = nullptr;
    .......
};
```

2. Modify PassVector() method to fill pointer:

```cpp
void DerivedFrame::PassVector(std::vector<wxString> & vwsM) {
    pvwsM3 = &vwsM;
}
```

3. Use pointer now:

```cpp
void DerivedFrame::USEvwsM() {
    assert(pvwsM3); // Check that we don't have null pointer, you may throw exception instead.
    pvwsM3->push_back("Something");
}
```

4. Remaining code is same as you have. Alternatively you may pass vector to constructor of DerivedFrame, which is more reliable than calling PassVector() separately (which you may forget to call, while constructor you always call):

```cpp
DerivedFrame::DerivedFrame(wxWindow* parent, std::vector<wxString> & vwsM)
    : OtherFrame( parent ) {
    this->PassVector(vwsM);
}
```

5. If you pass vector of strings to constructor only then you don't need a pointer, but reference in derived class, so instead of pointer field

```
class DerivedFrame: public OtherFrame {
    std::vector<wxString> * pvwsM3 = nullptr;
    .......
};
```

make reference field

```cpp
class DerivedFrame: public OtherFrame {
    std::vector<wxString> & rvwsM3;
    .......
};
```

then remove PassVector() method and add reference initialization in constructor:

```cpp
DerivedFrame::DerivedFrame(wxWindow* parent, std::vector<wxString> & vwsM)
    : OtherFrame( parent ), rvwsM3(vwsM) {}
```

and use it as a reference (unlike pointer reference doesn't need to be checked for null):

```cpp
void DerivedFrame::USEvwsM() {
    rvwsM3.push_back("Something");
}
```

Reference compared to pointer has two advantages - it can't be forgotten to be initialized, because with reference you don't need to call PassVector(), and you don't need to check if it is null unlike checking pointer (reference is never null). But reference can be initialized only in constructor, while pointer can be initialized later, far later after object was constructed.

Comment: Brilliant.    Thank you very, very much.    Exactly what I needed.    I started on this track, but failed miserably :-(.    It only took a short google search to find that I need pvwsM3->at(i) to access the individual strings.    Now I will take time to learn and understand why and how this works.   (I always want to know why, and how things work)

Comment: @Ruud Just now added `5.` part of my answer about how to use `reference` instead of `pointer`, please put a look at my answer again, look only at new part `5.`. Reference is only suitable for passing to constructor, but has advantage that you never forget to initialize it, because there is no need to call PassVector(), and secondly you don't need to check that it is null as was checking pointer.

Comment: I really like your reference suggestion. It makes working with the vector as you normally would.  Will take sometime for me to understand the workings, but its going to be worth every minute. Thank you for your excellent explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Having a global vector is bad practice, but anyhow typical for a settings like vector.

When I understand right, the vector you want to share, is known in the base like this

```
struct base {
    std::vector<std::string>& data;
    base(std::vector<std::string>& init) : data(init) {}
};

struct derived : base {
    derived(std::vector<std::string>& init) : base(init) {}
    void have_fun_with_VectorOfStrings();
};
```

it can be directly accessed in derived class, or any entity having access to one of the derived class.

Not sure if you might be looking for a different approach like the [singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) instead:

```
class coolStuff {
    public:
    std::vector<std::string> data;
    static coolStuff& get() {
        static coolStuff instance;
        return instance;
    }
    private:
    coolStuff () {
        // constructor called once using "get", so can be used for initialization
    }
};
```

This would be simply called anywhere you need it. Since only 1 instance exists, it might be a better approach to achieve the same.

```
coolStuff::get().data.push_back("add a new string");
```

You have shared a code example meanwhile, so your example would look like this applying approach 1 above.

```
class wxMainFrame: public GUIFrame {
    public:
        wxMainFrame(wxFrame *frame, std::vector<wxString>& vwsM3);
    private:
        std::vector<wxString>& vwsM3;
};

wxServerFrame::wxServerFrame(wxFrame *frame, std::vector<wxString>& _vwsM3) : GUIFrame(frame)
, vwsM3(_vwsM3)
{
    m_DerivedFrame = new DerivedFrame(this, _vwsM3);
    // m_DerivedFrame->PassVector(&vwsM3); // not needed anymore
}
// same for further inherited classes
```

If I may add a side note: It looks like you are doing some graphic-like stuff, so performance should be considered aswell: Try to avoid dynamic allocations like new, mallcoc, etc, since this is a very slow operation. An optimization might be to use a member in the class, instead of allocating to a member pointer at runtime.

Comment: Sometimes you overlook the simplest of things. However, by adding the reference to the vector in the class constructor as you suggested, only makes it available in the constructor, nowhere else :-(. Any ideas?

Comment: Making the edit in the MainFrame causes compile errors in the OnInit function >wxServerFrame* frame = new wxServerFrame(0L);<?. when adding the >, std::vector<wxString>& vwsM< in here as well) Any ideas?

Comment: This approach merges the `PassVector` method to the constructor, which assigns it to `vwsM3`. This requires the vector to be instanciated and passed at construction time. Since `vwsM3` is a (private) member of `wxMainFrame` it might be used by any method of  `wxMainFrame`. Not sure if `protected:` is a way you are looking for to access the vector from derived classses too. Not sure if I got that right.